# Editing Docker container FS using Atom/Sublime-Text?

Tags: docker, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I'm running OSX and Docker with the help of boot2docker.

From my understanding boot2docker is a lightweight linux distro that is running the docker containers. I have some Ubuntu containers that I use to run and test projects that should specifically run well on Linux.

However every small code change from my host text editor of choice, requires me to re-build image and re-run the container. Run the  app and confirm that the change I made didn't break something.

Is there a way for me to open a Docker container FS folder in a text editor from my host machine? (a.k.a Remote edit?)

Have any of you guys done this? Any ideas will be awesome. I think about setuping SFTP or SSHD on the Docker container, but I would want your opinion?

Comment: When not using `boot2docker` (e.g., when running on Linux), the standard solution is to use Docker volumes to expose your host filesystem inside the container.  I don't know what volume support is like when using boot2docker, so I don't know if this would be appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I often do is, in development, mount the source code of the application to its usual place in a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). Then, I set the command (or entrypoint) of the container to a script that launches it in "development mode" (for example, by using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) for a node.js application, setting `RAILS_ENV=development` in Rails, and so on).

Volumes *do* work on Mac OS X (and I assume Windows) under boot2docker or docker-machine, with the caveat that you need to be working somewhere beneath your home directory.

For a concrete example, here's [a repository](https://github.com/deconst/presenter) that I set this up in. The ingredients:

1. [`script/dev`](https://github.com/deconst/presenter/blob/master/script/dev#L12-L15) is my "dev-mode" entrypoint. It launches the main application under nodemon.
2. When I launch the container, I [mount the source directory into the container as a volume](https://github.com/deconst/presenter/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L34) and [set `script/dev` as the command](https://github.com/deconst/presenter/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L36). (I'm using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) here to launch and link in an upstream dependency, so I can do everything in one command.)

With those two things in place, I can run `docker-compose up`, make a source change in whatever editor I choose on my host, save the file, and the service within the container auto-reloads to bring my changes into effect. Presto!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer. Just tried your approach last week and it fit perfectly for my situation. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: i dont see any files in the folder, is there a video of it