# Saving files on Mac OSX host to Docker container (auto-reloading)

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This question has been asked here in many ways, but none of them seemed to be exactly what I'm looking for. **Note: I'm totally new to Docker.**

I've currently got a Docker image ("padcrawler") on my Mac, which is an image built off of scrapinghub/splash.

I'm basically just trying to make it so that any changes I make on my host machine (Mac), are automatically updated within the container. I'm using docker-machine and **NOT** boot2docker.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM scrapinghub/splash:latest

# Update UBUNTU base image and install deps
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    gcc \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    make \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    python-pip \
    python \
    python-dev \
    ssh \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/pad
WORKDIR /usr/src/pad

# Copy over everything to container directory
COPY . /usr/src/pad
# Install Python (2.7) deps
RUN /usr/bin/pip install -r /usr/src/pad/requirements.txt

# Launch pad-crawler upon docker container bootup
ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/pad/start
```

I'm also using docker-compose and this is my yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    crawler:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - ".:/usr/src/pad"
        image: padcrawler
```

However, I'm still unable to get any host file changes to automatically sync with the mounted volume in the container. Obviously it's annoying and frustrating to have to manually copy over the changes every-time. Is there a bigger issue here? I'm using Docker totally wrong?

Comment: I should add, this is the initial steps I was following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463219/editing-docker-container-fs-using-atom-sublime-text

Comment: Is Docker install in a VirtualBox VM or are you running Docker for Mac?

Comment: Note also that only your home folder is shared to your virtual machine, so your project has to be located under your home folder.